# Inserting regular expression in PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql

I would like to know how I can insert regular expression in a table column in a PostgreSQl table.

For example I have column called "rule" in a table where I need to store the expression ^[0-9]+$. I tried:

```
insert into rule_master(rule)
values('^[0-9]+$') where rule_id='7'
```

But I am getting error syntax near where is wrong. I tried this with and with out single quotes. Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to `UPDATE` an existing record. In that case you should do:

```
UPDATE rule_master
SET rule = '^[0-9]+$'
WHERE rule_id = '7';
```

But if this is indeed a new record and you want to `INSERT` that regex with the value of "rule_id" then do:

```
INSERT INTO rule_master(rule_id, rule)
VALUES ('7', '^[0-9]+$');
```

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but: if `rule_id` is a number (`int`, `bigint`, `serial`) , it shouldn't be compared to a string